# How do you create a has_many through relationship in a self joined table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I currently have a self joined table but when I try to create many to many updates, it can only store one relationship at a time. I looked at the has_many through relationship in the ruby on rails guide but it deals with the Employee Manager Subordinate case which is different from my example. How do you create a has_many :through relationship with a self joined table?

Word Model

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :synonyms, :foreign_key => 'synonym_id', :class_name => 'Word'
end
```

Example of what I'm trying to do

```
good = Word.create(name:'good')
pleasant = Word.create(name:'pleasant')
fine = Word.create(name:'fine')

good.synonyms << pleasant
good.synonyms << fine

pleasant.synonyms << good
pleasant.synonyms << fine

fine.synonyms << good
fine.synonyms << pleasant

good.synonyms # Empty - fine and pleasant should be resultset
pleasant.synonyms # Empty - good and fine should be in this resultset
fine.synonyms # Has the foreign keys to good and pleasant
```

Word Schema

```
create_table "words", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name", null: false
  t.integer  "synonym_id"
end
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: I don't think this design will work.  You're attempting to use a has_many relationship for a has_one database design.  A `Word` instance has one column to store synonym_id.  You either want to use a join table or use a database that will let you have an array column for synonym_ids.